# Spring Boot: Maunally bind an object from a webRequest using HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to build an object before it even reaches the controller and one way I found to do that is by using `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Basically, I have a pojo which gets mapped to the request parameters, but I want to set some other fields in that pojo before it reaches the controller.

POJO: UserParams.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserParams {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sessionId;
}
```

Let's say my request comes in as `localhost:8080/user?firstName=John&lastName=Doe`

So, in my resolver I want to bind the UserParams object using the request params from the above request and populate `sessionId` field and return the bound object with additional value.

```
@Component
public class UserParamsResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(UserParams.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter,
                                  final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  final NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        WebDataBinder binder = new WebDataBinder(BeanUtils.instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType()));
        ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues values = new ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues(((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest());
        binder.bind(values);
        BindingResult result = binder.getBindingResult();

        // UserParams userParams = how to get this object? 
        // userParams.setSessionId(userParams.getLastName + Math.random())
        return userParams;
}
```

So, when the request eventually reaches the controller, I've the userParams with sessionId in it.

I tried looking at many places (programcreek.com had lot of examples for WebDataBinder) and tried to find out how Spring binds the objects with request params before coming to the Controller, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use *spring AOP* in order to process all `@Controller` methods having `UserParams` as a parameter. Then you have to get access to `WebRequest` in order to get `sessionId` and this is a little bit trickier; you'll have to create a `@Bean @Scope("request")` (e.g. name it *WebRequestAccessor*) which to contain an `@Autowired` field of type `WebRequest`. Autowire that *WebRequestAccessor* bean into your `@Aspect` in order to use its `WebRequest` field which then gives you access to `sessionId`. Set the `sessionId` on the `UserParams` parameter then let the advised method continue its work.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/adrhc/requestbody-bindingresult/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/mvctries/web/aop/BindingErrorsHandler.java) about how to write & use an @Aspect.

**UPDATE**

You could use `JSESSIONID` instead of `HttpSession.getId()`. Just annotate `private String sessionId` with `@CookieValue("JSESSIONID")`.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm pretty sure you should use [ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) (or [ModelAttributeMethodProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html)) instead of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Comment: Is it not possible to make it work in the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver? The reason I need it in the resolver is because I want to make it more generic, so in future I can bind UserParams, OwnerParams, BuyerParams, etc using the same resolver class.

Comment: I don't know but you could make all these classes implement an interface (e.g. `SessionIdProvider`, having setter/getter for `sessionId`) then create the `@Aspect` based on that interface.